# ¿Cómo recoger un determinado numero de datos desde un formulario y luego insertarlos en una base de datos (php y mysql)?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un formulario donde genero varios inputs dentro de un ciclo for, lo que quisiera es saber como recupero esa información para luego insertarla en una base de datos.

Además quisiera poder validar que esos campos inputs solo me reciban:

- Números mayores o iguales a diez y menores que 100 (solo positivos).
- Que no se cargue la información a la base de datos si no se han llenado todos los campos.

Comment: Podrías anexar el código que has estado haciendo para apoyarte mejor?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<center>
<body>
<form>
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <?php for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) { ?>
   <td><input type="text" name="valor" size="2"> </td>
  <?php } ?>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</body>
</center>
</html>

Comment: Este es el formulario que tengo donde genero los inputs dentro del ciclo.

Comment: Conviene que pongas el formulario en la pregunta, no en un formulario. Es mejor que hagas la validación en Javascript y cuando todo esté correcto actives el botón enviar del form, para mandar los datos por Ajax al servidor para hacer la inserción. Me temo que tu pregunta es muy amplia, porque abarca muchos aspectos: validación de datos, envío de datos al servidor, tratamiento de datos para inserción. Hay varias preguntas aquí que explican esos aspectos. Conviene que investigues y plantees tus dudas sobre problemas concretos en tu intento de código.

Answer (score 0):

Para la primera parte, puedes usar el atributo MIN y el MAX de HTML para decirle cual es el valor mayor y el menor que puede recibir también debes cambiar el tipo text por tipo number para que solo acepte valores numéricos

```
<input type="number" min="10" max="100" name="valor" class="campo" size="2">
```

Para la segunda cuestión puedes usar JQuery para validar que los campos no estén vacíos, solo tienes que agregarle una clase a tu elemento HTML, después recorrer dicho elemento, y si pasa todas las validaciones, mandas guardar

```
function guardar(){
  $('.campo').each(function() {            
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        alert("No puede dejar el campo "+$(this).attr('id')+" vacio");
        return;
    }
  });

 //codigo para mandar guardar
}
```

Como puedes ver la función guardar, primero verifica que todos los campos estén llenos, si alguno esta vació hace un return para detener la ejecución y no pase al siguiente bloque que seria el de guardar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la colaboración.

Answer (score 0):

los name generados deben ser tipo array para que puedas obtener los valores

```
 <td><input type="number" name="valor[]" size="2">
```

Para recuoerar la informaación lo haces con un foreach

```
$valor = $_POST['valor'];
foreach( $valor as $llave => $val ) {
   ...//aca opbtienes la llave y el valor de cada input 
   //y haces lo que necesites
}
```

Las validaciones las puedes hacer en html5 el input debe ser tipo number y con atributo max para el valor maximo, para que sean obligatorios un required. 
Recomendable tambien hacer las validaciones en el lado del servidor lo cual puedes hacerlo con una expresion regular.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho..